Install github cli extension in Azure DevOps pipeline
I use a pipeline decorator in Azure DevOps to integrate with a change management system. I need to pass the user responsible for the change for this integration.
I am also in the process of migrating source code from Azure DevOps to GitHub (while keeping the AzDO pipelines) so the decorator needs to be enhanced to determine if the source is in GitHub or AzDO and get the user appropriately. I cannot rely on the AzDO pipeline var "BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL" as it will not be populated if the pipeline was kicked off by the PR process, so I need leverage the gh cli to get the committer email. All this works fine locally, but gh auth from the azdo pipeline is proving difficult.
I created a GH app, stored the app id, install id, and private key in an azdo library. I want to call "gh token generate" to get a token, but first I have to install it. When I try to install the extension in the pipeline with "gh extension install Link-/gh-token --force" I get:
To get started with GitHub CLI, please run:  gh auth login
Alternatively, populate the GH_TOKEN environment variable with a GitHub API authentication token.

Catch 22; I need a token to install the extension that lets me generate a token. When I run the generate token command locally it creates a short-lived token not suitable for storing so I need to create it dynamically.
Suggestions?

It reports same message when installing extension via command gh extension install Link-/gh-token directly on local machine.

To install the extension, you need to gh auth login firstly. While in DevOps pipeline, to automate the process, you have to pass github token for gh auth login command.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo $(GitHubPAT) | gh auth login --with-token
  displayName: 'Authenticate with GitHub CLI'
  env:
    GitHubPAT: $(GitHubPAT)

- script: gh extension install Link-/gh-token


I ended up creating a function with powershell-jwt so I don't have to store a PAT and avoid the whole gh extension problem altogether:
function Get-GitHubToken {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $GitHubAppId,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $GitHubAppInstallId,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $GitHubPrivateKey
    )

    install-module powershell-jwt -force
    $apiSecret = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($GitHubPrivateKey)
    $exp = [int][double]::parse((Get-Date -Date $((Get-Date).addseconds(300).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s))
    $iat = [int][double]::parse((Get-Date -Date $((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s))

    # create a Json Web Token using new-jwt from the powershell-jwt module
    $jwt = New-JWT -Algorithm "RS256" -Issuer $GitHubAppId -ExpiryTimestamp $exp -SecretKey $apiSecret -PayloadClaims @{ "iat" = $iat }

    $headers = @{
        "Accept"        = "application/vnd.github+json"
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $jwt"
    }

    $res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.github.com/app/installations/$GitHubAppInstallId/access_tokens" -Headers $headers -Method Post
    $json_res = ConvertFrom-Json($res.Content)
    $json_res.token
}

